# Windows 8 protocol uri run console program

Tags: c#, uri, console-application, windows-8.1, protocols

How can i register a C# console program to run with a protocol uri?

I want to call an run a console program with the tel:+0123456789 
I've fount a lot of information how to do it for Windows 7 or how to register a Windows 8 App with an protocol uri. 
Can someone point me to a solution, how i can do that for an Console Application in Windows 8?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1):

It's essentially the same for a Windows 8 or 8.1 desktop app as it is for Windows 7.

Register the URL in the registry:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   tel
      (Default) = "URL:Tel Protocol"
      URL Protocol = ""
      DefaultIcon
         (Default) = "mytelapp.exe,1"
      shell
         open
            command
               (Default) = "C:\Program Files\mytelapp\mytelapp.exe" "%1"
```

Since there are likely to be other apps who want to handle the tel protocol also add a pointer to your Capabilities registration under HKLM\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications

See [Registering the Application Handling the Custom URI Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=VS.85).aspx#app_reg) and [Best practices for file type and protocol associations in Windows Developer Preview desktop apps](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/3/A/43A474F2-5038-47BD-A4D3-ECD5EFE80192/Best%20practices%20for%20file%20type%20and%20protocol%20associations%20in%20Windows%208%20desktop%20apps.docx) and [Default Programs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: it is not the same as windows 8 and most certainly not in windows 10